# Integer number too large even when using Long type

Tags: java, long-integer

I have a problem when using Long type attributes, I created an attribute called 'Cnh' which receives a 11 digit code, I already put the L in the end of the value, but when I run it in JUnit it still says Integer number too large: 06161567318l.

Is there any possible way I can avoid it
I don't wanna change the attribute type, because I have another which has the same problem but it is a 'hashcode' (it would be really tough to change)

SetUp Values

```
public void setUp() {
    cli = new Cliente();
    cli.setEmail("lucasoaresleite@gmail.com");
    cli.setCpf(06161567318l);
    cli.setCnh(06161567318l);
    cli.setCnpj("--");
    cli.setDataNascimento("23081998");
    cli.setNomeCompleto("Lucas Soares");
    cli.setNomeFantasia("--");
}
```

JUnit Test

```
public void testSetCnh() {
    assertEquals(06161567318l, cli.getCnh());
}
```

public class Cliente implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "cpf")
private Long cpf;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "nome_completo")
private String nomeCompleto;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "data_nascimento")
private String dataNascimento;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "email")
private String email;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "cnh")
private Long cnh;
@Column(name = "cnpj")
private String cnpj;
@Column(name = "nome_fantasia")
private String nomeFantasia;

public Cliente() {
}

public Cliente(Long cpf) {
    this.cpf = cpf;
}

public Cliente(Long cpf, String nomeCompleto, String dataNascimento, String email, Long cnh) {
    this.cpf = cpf;
    this.nomeCompleto = nomeCompleto;
    this.dataNascimento = dataNascimento;
    this.email = email;
    this.cnh = cnh;
}

public Long getCpf() {
    return cpf;
}

public void setCpf(Long cpf) {
    this.cpf = cpf;
}

public String getNomeCompleto() {
    return nomeCompleto;
}

public void setNomeCompleto(String nomeCompleto) {
    this.nomeCompleto = nomeCompleto;
}

public String getDataNascimento() {
    return dataNascimento;
}

public void setDataNascimento(String dataNascimento) {
    this.dataNascimento = dataNascimento;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public Long getCnh() {
    return cnh;
}

public void setCnh(Long cnh) {
    this.cnh = cnh;
}

public String getCnpj() {
    return cnpj;
}

public void setCnpj(String cnpj) {
    this.cnpj = cnpj;
}

public String getNomeFantasia() {
    return nomeFantasia;
}

public void setNomeFantasia(String nomeFantasia) {
    this.nomeFantasia = nomeFantasia;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (cpf != null ? cpf.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Cliente)) {
        return false;
    }
    Cliente other = (Cliente) object;
    if ((this.cpf == null && other.cpf != null) || (this.cpf != null && !this.cpf.equals(other.cpf))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "alocar.java.models.Cliente[ cpf=" + cpf + " ]";
}
```

}

I need it to accept values way bigger than the limit(I know... but I also know you know what I'm talking about) ]:)

Comment: Note that numeric literals starting with `0` are interpreted as octal values .

Comment: Another important thing: if the thing you're handling is some kind of code (such as a phone number, ssn, ...), then handling it as an `int`, `long` or even `BigInteger` is almost certainly wrong. Those things are not "numbers" in the sense of "let's count". They are strings that happen to be restricted in the characters they can have. Most notably there's a difference between "0", "00" and "000" in these kinds of system, so leading 0 would be relevant (but they are never stored in the numeric types!).

Comment: I don't think that using numbers for CPF is the best choice, I would prefer String... (simple example why: zero at start of numbers are normally not relevant); and `dataNascimento` probably better represented by `LocalDate`

Comment: The problem, as @Arnaud has commented, seems to be that numbers with a leading 0 are octal values. In octal notation, accepted values are between 0 and 7. Your number has an 8, thus, it's not a valid octal number. Try removing (or replacing) the leading 0 (and use L instead of l to avoid confusion with number 1!!!)

Comment: thanks guys <3 I think I'm gonna do as @CarlosHeuberger said, and thy using string instead of Long/Int for CPF